# Am I Really Using A Real-Time Kernel?

Tags: testing, kernel, ubuntu-12.04, real-time

So I built my own Ubuntu 12.04.4 kernel from source code and applied a real-time patch to it. I want to be sure that I am indeed running a real-time kernel. I tried using ltp, but was getting confused about how to read the information. Is there an easy way to tell if my kernel really is real-time?

Any help is appreciated!

George

Comment: What kernel? You realize there's more than one... Windows has a kernel, for example.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the catch. I just updated my post. I'm using a custom Ubuntu 12.04.4 kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see whether the currently running kernel has the RT_PREEMPT patch, use uname and look for PREEMPT and RT:

```
ubuntu10:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu10 2.6.31-11-rt #154-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT RT Wed Jun 9 12:28:53 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

If you are asking for evidence or proof of RT_PREEMPT's real-time performance, search the Internet, there are a lot of options. Here is one place to start: http://elinux.org/Realtime_Testing_Best_Practices

Comment: I should have made my question more specific, I was looking for proof that the kernel is actually operating in real-time. I just took a quick glance at the link and it looks like some good stuff @slowjelj

Answer (score 1):

First you have to know what a real-time kernel is--or at least what you think it is or want from it. That's a tough job since there is not a clear consensus in the real-time computing community on what "real-time" means. To see that, read vendor literature, see continuing education courses and even academic (inevitably "embedded system") courses, follow the forums on the web, read the practitioner magazines (e.g., RTC, etc.). The "consensus", to paraphrase Justice Potter Stuart, is "I don't know what "real-time" means, but I know it when I see it." There can be no answer to your question until you ask a question that specifies what "real-time kernel" means to you (at least).

Then you can define and apply tests such as the duration of interrupt and kernel service times, predictability of those durations, task pre-emptability, prevention and minimization of the duration of task eligibility (usually priorities), and a whole host of other issues that are described in great detail on the web.

BTW, the term "kernel" is also controversial. Historically in the OS community, it has meant the lowest level mechanisms in kernel space, on which the OS is built in user space. The embedded systems community instead typically uses it to mean a minimal "OS," what the mainstream OS community has meant by "executive."

I address this in precise detail on my web site but unfortunately I have it in maintenance mode while I am updating it.

I am also gradually answering this and other related questions comment by comment in a discussion in the LinkedIn RTOS group.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I will have to do some more research on RT and kernels I guess.